# How to install multiple packages via pacman in a single command?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Is it possible to install multiple packages via a single pacman command?

E.g.

```
Pacman -S package_1,package_2
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes from [pacman wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman)  To install a single package or list of packages (including dependencies), issue the following command:

`# pacman -S package_name1 package_name2 ..`

Comment: Ah, so my issue was the commas ... Thanks!

Comment: I didn't notice the commas ;)